# GridBagConstraints not working properly? Need to start at far left of panel

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm setting a panel, and I'm using a GridBagLayout. However, when I'm setting up the panel, the labels are not aranging the way I want (I want them to read like a statsheet) The rotationLabels should be showing on the far left, but they are showing in the middle. Am I missing something in my code?

```
GridBagConstraints rotationGB = new GridBagConstraints();
            rotationGB.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
            rotationGB.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            rotationPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            rotationLabels = new JLabel[countStarters(team)];
            eraArray = new JLabel[countStarters(team)];
            winArray = new JLabel[countStarters(team)];
            lossArray = new JLabel[countStarters(team)];
            savesArray = new JLabel[countStarters(team)];
            bsArray = new JLabel[countStarters(team)];
            resetXY(0,0);
            for(int i = 0; i < countStarters(team); i++){
                labelX = 0;
                final int n = i;
                rotationLabels[i] = new JLabel(team.rotation.get(i).getName());
                    //Label setup code
                //Mouse listener stuff

                addGCComp(rotationLabels[i], rotationPanel, rotationGB, labelX, labelY, labelSize);
                labelX += 125;
                eraArray[i] = new JLabel(pitcherF.format(team.rotation.get(i).getERA()));
                eraArray[i].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                addGCComp(eraArray[i], rotationPanel, rotationGB, labelX, labelY, labelSize);
                labelX += 75;
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0");
                winArray[i] = new JLabel(df.format(team.rotation.get(i).getPitcherWins()));
                winArray[i].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                addGCComp(winArray[i], rotationPanel, rotationGB, labelX, labelY, labelSize);
                labelX += 75;
                lossArray[i] = new JLabel(df.format(team.rotation.get(i).getPitcherLosses()));
                lossArray[i].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                addGCComp(lossArray[i], rotationPanel, rotationGB, labelX, labelY, labelSize);
                labelX += 75;
                savesArray[i] = new JLabel(df.format(team.rotation.get(i).getPitcherSaves()));
                savesArray[i].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                addGCComp(savesArray[i], rotationPanel, rotationGB, labelX, labelY, labelSize);
                labelX += 75;
                bsArray[i] = new JLabel(df.format(team.rotation.get(i).getPitcherBlownSaves()));
                bsArray[i].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                addGCComp(bsArray[i], rotationPanel, rotationGB, labelX, labelY, labelSize);
                labelX += 75;

                labelY += 25;
            }
```

What am I missing? I tried GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST for an anchor, but that didn't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers, 
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the Gridbaglayout and then add the Components to be layout by it.

Like this

```
GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();

layout.addLayoutComponent(Component, cons);
```

then add the layout to the Container.

Comment: Fixed it... silly my I had to adjust the weightx of the constraints